# How to force a Case/Bug reference to be entered in TortoiseHG commit comment?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, fogbugz

We are trying to get TortoiseHG 2.0.5 to check that a fogbugz case number has been entered in the commit comment, investigations have shown a "mandatory issue reference" is available in TortoiseHG that requires the link.regex to be valid. We already use the Issue and Issue link with the fogbugz expression to convert a case into a link to the fogbugz site, so that works. All we want to do is force/remind that a case has to be entered in the changeset commit comment

The "mandatory issue reference" setting does not appear in the UI of this version, we have edited the settings file adding "issue.linkmandatory=True" but this does not seem to work.

Any ideas if this should work or how to achieve what we want.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TortoiseHg went through a major rewrite between 1.1.9 and 2.0 where the underlying GUI framework was changed from GTK to Qt. This meant that practically all functionality had to be rewritten. Features that were not used by the developers or not requested by the community were simply not ported.

I suggest you first raise your question at the users discussion mail list tortoisehg-discuss, either via email to tortoisehg-discuss@lists.sourceforge.net or via [the gmane web forum of the mail list](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.mercurial.tortoisehg.user).

If there is no way to configure the new version to get the behavior you want, you could then raise it as an enhancement issue at  https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issues?status=new&status=open - but the only 100% certain way to get the feature would be to  offer development resources that can port the feature. The TortoiseHg team is usually very supportive. You don't need a deep understanding of GTK, Qt, or TortoiseHg - merely some time to do it. I guess it could be done in a day or two.